# Add_axes colorbar object not saving to figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm attempting to save a four-panel plot with added colorbar as an .eps figure, however, only the panel plot is saved, cutting off the colorbar from add_axes that is supposed to be at the bottom of the plot. Does anyone have an idea of how to make sure the colorbar gets saved? Code is below, thanks.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,3.75))

ax = plt.subplot(221) 
lats,lons = wrf.latlon_coords(totrain)
bm = wrf.get_basemap(rainc)
bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawstates(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,5.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[1,0,0,0])
bm.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,15.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[0,0,0,1])
x,y = bm(wrf.to_np(lons),wrf.to_np(lats))  
cx1 = bm.contourf(x,y,wrf.to_np(all_rain[0]),np.arange(0,np.max(all_rain)+15,15),cmap=cmap)
text_box = AnchoredText('a)',frameon=False,loc=2,pad=0.1,prop=dict(fontweight='bold',fontsize=10.))
plt.setp(text_box.patch,facecolor='white',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(text_box)

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
lats,lons = wrf.latlon_coords(totrain)
bm = wrf.get_basemap(rainc)
bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawstates(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,5.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[1,0,0,0])
bm.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,15.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[0,0,0,1])
x,y = bm(wrf.to_np(lons),wrf.to_np(lats))
cx2=bm.contourf(x,y,wrf.to_np(all_rain[1]),np.arange(0,np.max(all_rain)+15,15),cmap=cmap)
text_box = AnchoredText('b)',frameon=False,loc=2,pad=0.1,prop=dict(fontweight='bold',fontsize=10.))
plt.setp(text_box.patch,facecolor='white',alpha=0.5)
ax2.add_artist(text_box)

ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
lats,lons = wrf.latlon_coords(totrain)
bm = wrf.get_basemap(rainc)
bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawstates(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,5.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[1,0,0,0])
bm.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,15.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[0,0,0,1])
x,y = bm(wrf.to_np(lons),wrf.to_np(lats))  
cx3=bm.contourf(x,y,wrf.to_np(all_rain[2]),np.arange(0,np.max(all_rain)+15,15),cmap=cmap)
text_box = AnchoredText('c)',frameon=False,loc=2,pad=0.1,prop=dict(fontweight='bold',fontsize=10.))
plt.setp(text_box.patch,facecolor='white',alpha=0.5)
ax3.add_artist(text_box)

ax4 = plt.subplot(224)  
lats,lons = wrf.latlon_coords(totrain)
bm = wrf.get_basemap(rainc)
bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawstates(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
bm.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,5.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[1,0,0,0])
bm.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,15.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[0,0,0,1])
x,y = bm(wrf.to_np(lons),wrf.to_np(lats))  
cx4=bm.contourf(x,y,wrf.to_np(all_rain[3]),np.arange(0,np.max(all_rain)+15,15),cmap=cmap)
text_box = AnchoredText('d)',frameon=False,loc=2,pad=0.1,prop=dict(fontweight='bold',fontsize=10.))
plt.setp(text_box.patch,facecolor='white',alpha=0.5)
ax4.add_artist(text_box)

fig.tight_layout()

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2,-0.075,0.6,0.05])
fig.colorbar(cx4,cax=cbar_ax,shrink=0.7,orientation='horizontal',label='Accumulated Precipitation (mm)')

fig.savefig('/strm3/vecellio/Figures/Figure4Final.eps',dpi=300.)
```

Comment: As seen by the coordinate `-0.075`, the colorbar is outside the figure boundary. You can probably get away with changing the savefig bounding box,  `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches="tight")`, but in general I would recommend putting everything *inside* the figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Adding bbox_inches worked, thank you! However, I'd like to ask you about the add_axes coordinates, if you don't mind. How would I ensure the colorbar is below my plots while still using a positive coordinate?

Comment: Probably by using `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)` or any number that would allow your colorbar to take strictly positive figure coordinates.